# what can be the workflow to get notification email when someone login to azure portal using logic apps and functions?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-logic-apps, azure-log-analytics

I want to create a workflow that when even any user login to my azure portal I get a notification email with the user id that has logged in.

Answer (score 0):

In General you can do this via AD audit logs streaming. To do this you need an Azure Active Directory **P1** or **P2** license

[image]

First of all go to **Active Directory** in Azure portal -> **Monitoring** -> **Sign-ins**
and click **Export Data Settings**. Create new **diagnostic setting** something like:

[image]

Make sure that you have selected SignInLogs. After that, login events will be sent to EventHub.

Finally, create an Azure Function that will be responsible for sending Email after an event triggered in the Event Hub.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-event-hubs-trigger?tabs=csharp

Comment: the sign in data is not streaming to event hub.

Comment: @Tushar are you assign P1 or P2 AD license to user (users)?